# I want to add following rows using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am creating a function for adding number of rows with input and select box in the table...
the structure of my page is....

```
<!--FROM HERE-->
<tr>
  <th>Track 1:</th>
  <td><input name="track[]" type="text" class="track" maxlength="150" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();"/>
      <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;"><img src="images/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 50px;" alt="upArrow" />
        <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">&nbsp;</div>
      </div></td>
  <td><img width="27" height="27" src="images/error.png" alt="Error" class="error" id="errorcategory"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Category:</th>
  <td ><select name="category" id="category" style="width:318px;">
      <?php getsongcategory($category); ?>
  </select></td>
  <td><img width="27" height="27" src="images/error.png" alt="Error" class="error" id="errorcategory"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th valign="top" style="padding-top:12px;">Poet:</th>
  <td ><select name="poetid" id="poetid" style="width:318px;">
      <?php fetch_poet_name($poetid); ?>
    </select><br/><br/>
    <input name="poetname" type="text" id="poetname"  maxlength="80" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" style="display:none;"/>
      <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;"><img src="images/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 50px;" alt="upArrow" />
        <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">&nbsp;</div>
      </div></td>
  <td><img width="27" height="27" src="images/error.png" alt="Error" class="error" id="errorpoetid" ></td>

</tr>  
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" id="track_1">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<!---TILL HERE->
```

I want to add this whole html next to `id="track_1"`. Hows that is possible?? As I have idea to add input and select in various ways....

```
$("<select/>", {
    class: 'selectdoctor',
    name: 'selectdoctor' + i,
    id: 'selectdoctor' + i
}).appendTo("#prescriptiondiv").after("<br/>");


$("<input/>", {
    type: 'text',
    class: 'textinput',
    name: 'textinput' + i,
    id: 'textinput' + i
}).appendTo("#prescriptiondiv").after("<br/><input type='file' id='imageinput"+ i +"' class='imageinput' /><br/><br/>");
```

Comment: You want to insert all of that html into a spot that is WITHIN the html you're trying to insert? That'd cause a DOM error, as a dom tree cannot be self-referential.

Comment: You have to use CSS selectors with `$()`, so `$("select")` and `$("input")`.

Answer (score 0):

If I where you, consider using a template file that holds your html and with JavaScript append it to the desire location. I use the [icanhaz](http://icanhazjs.com/) templating library.

Comment: OK got a idea about it.... But let me know how to start with ... Means what selectors need to be choose to add next to `track_id`